# Can you use clustering models such as k-mean or knn to do feature binning?

Tags: classification, clustering, binning

I currently working with a financial dataset in Python which contains a feature (among many others) called "interest rate", which represents the interest rate that a certain loan would have.

The feature vector would look something like this:

`{int_rate: [2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 3.1, 3.5, 4.1, 3.8, 2.9,....]}`

What I am trying to do is to group/bin this feature into categories, so I can:

1. Use a classification model
2. Give more flexibility (and maybe more accuracy) to my model to predict a category rather than a specific continuous number

My questions are:

1. Can you use clustering methods to categorise these values to get the most efficient bins?
2. or Would it be sensible to simply put the bins in a range of 0.5 for each? (bin 1 = from 2.0 to 2.5, etc)

I know how to do this with code and I am just a bit insecure about my approach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discretizing/Binning Continuous Variable by Continuous Response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296382/discretizing-binning-continuous-variable-by-continuous-response)

Comment: Don't bin or discretize your data. It only throws information away for no good reason. See my answer to the proposed duplicate, especially the link to Frank Harrell's explanation. Also see [Why reducing a regression model into a classification model by output discretization improves a model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/278196/1352) If you need more flexibility, use splines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but be careful if you are planning to do a performance test (such as cross-validation).

In that case, you need to define the clusters using the training set and project the test features on the training clusters. For instance, if you discretize the training features using k-means, the test features can be assigned to the closest cluster (be careful about which distance you want to use).